# Matlab - Optimize blend of two stream sub constraint to max profit

Tags: excel, matlab, optimization

I am trying to port a very simple Excel into a Matlab code (I am not completely satisfied with Excel Solver!). My problem is this:

I have two materials (say A and B) with their properties (density, visco, etc) and prices, and I mix them to obtain a third material (say C), whose properties are a mix (non necessarily linear) of the two, and which, if it respects some limits (ie density max X, visco max Y), can be sold for a certain price. What I have is a function which takes the quantity of A and B, their properties, their prices, material C limits, and material C price. It then comes up with a profit (i.e. price C * (quantity A + quantity B) - (price A * quantity A + price B * quantity B) ), and an indicator which tells me if all the properties limits are satisfied in material C (basically it compares limits and actual properties, and puts 0 if ok and 1 otherwise ---> if all properties are respected, mean of that vector should be 0).

Thus I have:

[profit, ok] = blend([qA, qB], [specA, specB], [pA, pB], [limits], pC)

and I want to max profit by changing quantity A and quantity B, sub that the ok vector is 0 and qA+qB is less than a specified max quantity. The real problem is imposing the ok vector equal to 0. I thought about porting the limit check outside of the function, but I can only check if the limits are respected once the function has calculated the property of the blends, so I cannot put that outside. Is there a solution to this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are looking for is called [nonlinear constrained optimization](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/constrained-optimization.html), and most likely specifically the function `fmincon`

I am afraid, that it is probably best if you unpack your function to fit into the standard scheme. This is incidentally a very good thing to learn, as this is the common way to express such problems.
The call is

```
x=fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon)
```

You have two parameters, giving the quantities of your materials, or if you normalize the total quantity to 1, you could get by with just one parameter x and express the other as (1-x) in all equations.
So you would need to write one function `fun`, that just computes the profit based on the parameters. 
The material constraints are then put into the remaining parameters. You could put all constraints into the `ceq` return of `nonlcon`, as explained [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#inputarg_nonlcon) to return zero when the mix is ok.

However, cleaner and more efficient is to encode all linear constraints using the `A` and `b` matrices.

For more details I would require the actual constraints and functions that you have.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I had missed the nonlcon from the fmincon help. This surely is quicker than writing the constraints in matrix form (even if it would be cleaner). So now I have this:

fun = @(x)blendoptim(x, visco, density),
[x, fval, iter] = fmincon(fun, quantityton, A, b,[] ,[] ,lb, ub, @(x)nonlcon(x, visco, density),
with function [c, ceq] = nonlcon(quantityton, visco, density)
and all the calculations on visco and density constraints happen there!